# How to initialize same named props in Child container components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, material-ui

I am quite new to React and it's functionality and best practice... So there is a possibility I am butchering this. I think the question will be quite long, I hope I won't make it, too complicated. Anyway...

I have a component for TableHead - which extends some material-ui components. This should be universal component for multiple tables, hence the PanelTableProps, etc. (you see the implementations below the first code snippet).

The problem is that when I access the TrackingPage (which is routed component) the SearchSettings are not defined (although I have initial state set in child container components - PanelsTable and OverlaysTable).

Before I had it all inside TrackingPage, but I had to change naming of SearchSettings for PanelSearchSettings nad OverlaySearchSettings... I thought that was the problem why TableHeadExtended didn't know from which prop it should get it. But after I separated it in to standalone components the problem is still here.

**TableHeadExtentder - component**

```
import * as React from 'react';

import TableCell, { SortDirection } from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';

import TableSortLabel from '@material-ui/core/TableSortLabel';

import { IColumn } from './../../model/typesDecorations';

import { SortOrder, PanelTableProps, OverlayTableProps, PanelABTestTableProps, OverlayABTestTableProps } from './../../model/types';
import { PanelSearchMember, OverlaySearchMember } from './../../api/generated/models';

export interface IProps {
    columns: Array<IColumn>,
    disabled?: boolean
}

type IComponentProps = IProps & (PanelTableProps | OverlayTableProps | PanelABTestTableProps | OverlayABTestTableProps);

const TableHeadExtend: React.FC<IComponentProps> = (props: IComponentProps): JSX.Element => {

    const { columns, searchSettings, onSearchSettingsChange } = props;

    const getSortHandler = (sortMember?: string) => () => {
        if (sortMember) {
            let sortMemberMethod;
            switch (true) {
                case props as PanelTableProps != null: {
                    sortMemberMethod = getPanelSearchMember();
                    break;
                }
                case props as OverlayTableProps != null: {
                    sortMemberMethod = getOverlaySearchMember();
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    sortMemberMethod = getPanelSearchMember();
                    break;
                }
            }
            onSearchSettingsChange && onSearchSettingsChange({
                sortMember: sortMemberMethod as any,
                sortOrder: getNextSortOrder()
            });
        }
    };

    const getPanelSearchMember = (): PanelSearchMember | undefined => {
        if (searchSettings.sortMember === undefined) {
            return PanelSearchMember.ButtonTypeCode
        } else if (searchSettings.sortMember === PanelSearchMember.ButtonTypeCode) {
            return PanelSearchMember.ButtonTypeCode;
        } else if (searchSettings.sortMember === PanelSearchMember.ButtonText) {
            return PanelSearchMember.ButtonText;
        } else if (searchSettings.sortMember === PanelSearchMember.Text) {
            return PanelSearchMember.Text;
        }
    }

    const getOverlaySearchMember = (): OverlaySearchMember | undefined => {
        if (searchSettings.sortMember === undefined) {
            return OverlaySearchMember.ButtonTypeCode
        } else if (searchSettings.sortMember === OverlaySearchMember.ButtonTypeCode) {
            return OverlaySearchMember.ButtonTypeCode;
        } else if (searchSettings.sortMember === OverlaySearchMember.ButtonText) {
            return OverlaySearchMember.ButtonText;
        } else if (searchSettings.sortMember === OverlaySearchMember.Text) {
            return OverlaySearchMember.Text;
        } else if (searchSettings.sortMember === OverlaySearchMember.OverlayAlignTypeCode) {
            return OverlaySearchMember.OverlayAlignTypeCode;
        }
    }

    const getNextSortOrder = (): SortOrder | undefined => {
        if (searchSettings.sortOrder === undefined) {
            return SortOrder.Ascending
        } else if (searchSettings.sortOrder === SortOrder.Ascending) {
            return SortOrder.Descending;
        } else if (searchSettings.sortOrder === SortOrder.Descending) {
            return SortOrder.Ascending;
        }
    }

    const getSortDirection = (): SortDirection => {
        return getDirection() || false;
    };

    const getDirection = (): 'asc' | 'desc' | undefined => {
        if (!searchSettings.sortOrder) {
            return undefined;
        }
        return (searchSettings.sortOrder.valueOf() === SortOrder.Ascending.valueOf()) ? 'asc' : 'desc';
    };

    return (
        <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
                {columns.map(column => (
                    <TableCell
                        key={column.id}
                        align={column.align}
                        sortDirection={searchSettings.sortMember === column.id ? getSortDirection() : false}
                    >
                        <TableSortLabel
                            active={!!column.sortMember && searchSettings.sortMember === column.sortMember}
                            direction={searchSettings.sortMember === column.sortMember ? getDirection() : undefined}
                            onClick={getSortHandler(column.sortMember)}
                            disabled={!column.sortMember || props.disabled}
                        >
                            {column.label}
                        </TableSortLabel>
                    </TableCell>
                ))}
            </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
    );
}

export default TableHeadExtend;
```

All table props are similar, at least they have some common properties, but "SearchSettings" are generated based on API classes, therefore there is no common parent. Basically it defines what settings should be used for searches for data (API calls) + it manages ordering, etc.

```
export interface PanelTableProps {
    searchSettings: IPanelSearchSettings,
    filterValues: IStringMap<any>,
    onSearchSettingsChange: (searchSettings: IPanelSearchSettings) => void,
    onFilterChange: (filterValues: IStringMap<any>) => void,
}
```

So I have this Parent component called TrackingPage which is defined for whole page. This one contains two tables - therefore PanelTableProps & OverlayTableProps. I am passing their ...props inside the child components - PanelsTable and OverlaysTable

**TrackingPage - component**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { withRouter, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';

import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Fab from '@material-ui/core/Fab';
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab';

import { TabPanel, a11yProps } from '../../../components/tab'

import i18n from "../../../locales/i18n";

import { IDataPage, PanelTableProps, OverlayTableProps } from '../../../model/types';
import { IPanel, IOverlay } from '../../../api/generated/models';

import { addTrackingRoute } from '../../routes';

import queryString from 'query-string';
import PanelsTable from './tables/PanelsTable';
import OverlaysTable from './tables/OverlaysTable';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
        marginTop: "20px"
    },
    container: {
        maxHeight: 440,
    },
    label: {
        fontSize: "xx-large",
    },
    div: {
        width: '60%',
        margin: "auto",
    },
    fab: {
        float: "right"
    }
});

export interface IProps {
    panelsLoading: boolean,
    panels: IDataPage<IPanel>,
    overlaysLoading: boolean,
    overlays: IDataPage<IOverlay>,
    loadData: () => void,
}

type IComponentProps = IProps & RouteComponentProps & PanelTableProps & OverlayTableProps;

const TrackingPage: React.FC<IComponentProps> = (props: IComponentProps): JSX.Element => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [load, setLoad] = React.useState<boolean>(true);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (load) {
            props.loadData();
            setLoad(false);
        }
    }, [load, props.loadData]);

    const handleAdd = () => {
        props.history.push(addTrackingRoute());
    };

    const getTab = () => {
        try {
            const search = queryString.parse(props.location.search);
            let tab = !!search && search.tab as string;
            tab = tab || "overview";

            switch (tab) {
                case 'overview': {
                    return 0;
                }
                case 'detailed': {
                    return 1;
                }
                case 'archive': {
                    return 2;
                }
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    };

    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(getTab());

    const handleChange = (event: any, newValue: number) => {
        setValue(newValue);

        switch (newValue) {
            case 0: {
                props.history.push({
                    pathname: '/tracking',
                    search: '?tab=overview'
                });
                break;
            }
            case 1: {
                props.history.push({
                    pathname: '/tracking',
                    search: '?tab=detailed'
                });
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                props.history.push({
                    pathname: '/tracking',
                    search: '?tab=archive'
                });
                break;
            }
        }
    };
    
    return (
        <div>
            <AppBar position="sticky">
                <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="Tracking tabs">
                    <Tab label="Overview" {...a11yProps(0)} />
                    <Tab label="Detailed" {...a11yProps(1)} />
                    <Tab label="Archive" {...a11yProps(2)} />
                </Tabs>
            </AppBar>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
                <label className={classes.label}>{i18n.t("tracking.list.label")}</label>
                <Fab className={classes.fab} size="small" color="primary" aria-label="add" onClick={handleAdd}>
                    <AddIcon />
                </Fab>
                <Paper className={classes.root}>
                    <PanelsTable {...props as IProps & RouteComponentProps & PanelTableProps} />
                    <OverlaysTable {...props as IProps & RouteComponentProps & OverlayTableProps} />
                </Paper>
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
                Item Two
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
                Item Three
            </TabPanel>
        </div>
    );
}

export default withRouter(TrackingPage);
```

The container for TrackingPage is defined like this. I am not sure what is supposed to be called here and what is supposed to be called inside the child components.

**TrackingPage - container**

```
import { AnyAction } from 'redux';
import { ThunkDispatch } from 'redux-thunk';
import { connect, MapDispatchToProps, MapStateToProps } from 'react-redux';
import { IAppState } from '../../../store/rootReducer';
import { IDataPage} from '../../../model/types';
import { IPanel, IOverlay } from '../../../api/generated/models';
import component from '../components/TrackingPage';
import { getPanels, getPanelsProcessing } from '../../../store/stream/tracking/panel/selectors';
import { getOverlays, getOverlaysProcessing } from '../../../store/stream/tracking/overlay/selectors';
import { loadPanels } from '../../../store/stream/tracking/panel/actions';
import { loadOverlays } from '../../../store/stream/tracking/overlay/actions';

interface IOwnProps {

}

interface IStateProps {
    panelsLoading: boolean,
    panels: IDataPage<IPanel>,
    overlaysLoading: boolean,
    overlays: IDataPage<IOverlay>,
}

interface IDispatchProps {
    loadData: () => void,
}

const mapStateToProps: MapStateToProps<
    IStateProps,
    IOwnProps,
    IAppState
> = (state: IAppState, ownProps: IOwnProps): IStateProps => ({
    panels: getPanels(state.stream.panel),
    panelsLoading: getPanelsProcessing(state.stream.panel),
    overlays: getOverlays(state.stream.overlay),
    overlaysLoading: getOverlaysProcessing(state.stream.overlay),
    ...ownProps
});

const mapDispatchToProps: MapDispatchToProps<
    IDispatchProps,
    IOwnProps
> = (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<{}, {}, AnyAction>) => ({
    loadData: async () => {
        dispatch(loadPanels());
        dispatch(loadOverlays());
    },
});

export default connect<
    IStateProps,
    IDispatchProps,
    IOwnProps,
    IAppState
>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(component);
```

Here is what PanelsTable component looks like (OverlaysTable is almost the same, except the actual props interfaces and models). TableHeadExtended is used inside, I expected that the SearchSettings would be set after initialization in PanelsTable container (snippet on the bottom), but it is undefined.

**PanelsTable - component**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { withRouter, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';

import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TablePagination from '@material-ui/core/TablePagination';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Fab from '@material-ui/core/Fab';
import EditIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';

import TableHeadExtended from '../../../../components/table/table-head';
import TableFilterExtended from '../../../../components/table/table-filter';

import { IDataPage, PanelTableProps, } from '../../../../model/types';
import { IPanel, IShortLink } from '../../../../api/generated/models';

import { generateColumns, DecoratorType } from '../../../../model/typesDecorations';

import { editTrackingRoute, detailTrackingRoute } from '../../../routes';

import { LinearProgress } from '@material-ui/core';

const panelColumns = generateColumns(DecoratorType.Panel);

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
        marginTop: "20px"
    },
    container: {
        maxHeight: 440,
    },
    label: {
        fontSize: "xx-large",
    },
    div: {
        width: '60%',
        margin: "auto",
    },
    fab: {
        float: "right"
    }
});

export interface IProps {
    panelsLoading: boolean,
    panels: IDataPage<IPanel>,
    loadData: () => void,
}

type IComponentProps = IProps & RouteComponentProps & PanelTableProps;

const PanelsTable: React.FC<IComponentProps> = (props: IComponentProps): JSX.Element => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [load, setLoad] = React.useState<boolean>(true);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (load) {
            props.loadData();
            setLoad(false);
        }
    }, [load, props.loadData]);

    const handleChangePagePanels = (event: any, newPage: number) => {
        !props.panelsLoading && props.onSearchSettingsChange({ pageNumber: newPage + 1, isTrackingOnly: true });
    };

    const handleChangeRowsPerPagePanels = (event: any) => {
        !props.panelsLoading && props.onSearchSettingsChange({ pageNumber: 1, pageSize: event.target.value, isTrackingOnly: true });
    };

    const handleEdit = (event: any, id: number) => {
        const route = editTrackingRoute(id);
        props.history.push(route);
    };

    const handleDetail = (event: any, id: number) => {
        const route = detailTrackingRoute(id);
        props.history.push(route);
    };

    console.log("TrackingPage [columns]: ", panelColumns);
    console.log("TrackingPage [props.panels]: ", props.panels);

    const renderProcessingPanels = (): JSX.Element | null => {
        if (!props.panelsLoading) {
            return null;
        }
        return (<TableRow >
            <TableCell colSpan={panelColumns.length} >
                <LinearProgress />
            </TableCell>
        </TableRow>)
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <TableFilterExtended columns={panelColumns} disabled={props.panelsLoading} {...props as PanelTableProps} />
            <TableContainer className={classes.container}>
                <Table stickyHeader aria-label="sticky table">
                    <TableHeadExtended columns={panelColumns} disabled={props.panelsLoading} {...props as PanelTableProps} />
                    <TableBody>
                        {!props.panelsLoading && (props.panels.data || []).map(p => {
                            return (
                                <TableRow hover role="checkbox" tabIndex={-1} key={p.id}>
                                    {panelColumns.map(column => {
                                        const value = (p as any)[column.id];
                                        const shortLink = value as IShortLink;

                                        if (column.id === 'loads') {
                                            return (
                                                <TableCell key={column.id} align={column.align} >
                                                    {column.format ? column.format(shortLink.loads) : shortLink.loads}
                                                </TableCell>
                                            );
                                        }

                                        if (column.id === 'clicks') {
                                            return (
                                                <TableCell key={column.id} align={column.align} >
                                                    {column.format ? column.format(shortLink.clicks) : shortLink.clicks}
                                                </TableCell>
                                            );
                                        }

                                        if (column.id === 'conversion') {
                                            return (
                                                <TableCell key={column.id} align={column.align} >
                                                    {column.format ? column.format(shortLink.conversionRate) : shortLink.conversionRate}
                                                </TableCell>
                                            );
                                        }

                                        if (column.id === 'controls') {
                                            return (
                                                <TableCell key={column.id} align={column.align} >
                                                    <Fab className={classes.fab} size="small" color="primary" aria-label="add" onClick={event => handleDetail(event, p.id)}>
                                                        <SearchIcon />
                                                    </Fab>
                                                    <Fab className={classes.fab} size="small" color="primary" aria-label="add" onClick={event => handleEdit(event, p.id)}>
                                                        <EditIcon />
                                                    </Fab>
                                                </TableCell>
                                            );
                                        }

                                        return (
                                            <TableCell key={column.id} align={column.align} >
                                                {column.format ? column.format(value) : value}
                                            </TableCell>
                                        );
                                    })}
                                </TableRow>
                            );
                        })}
                        {renderProcessingPanels()}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </TableContainer>
            <TablePagination
                rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 25, 50, 100]}
                component="div"
                count={props.panels.totalCount}
                rowsPerPage={props.panels.pageSize}
                page={props.panels.pageNumber - 1}
                onChangePage={handleChangePagePanels}
                onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPagePanels}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

export default withRouter(PanelsTable);
```

This is the PanelsTable container. Here I initialize SearchSettings, but this is never called.

**PanelsTable - container**

```
import { AnyAction } from 'redux';
import { ThunkDispatch } from 'redux-thunk';
import { connect, MapDispatchToProps, MapStateToProps } from 'react-redux';
import { IAppState } from '../../../../store/rootReducer';
import { IDataPage, IStringMap} from '../../../../model/types';
import { IPanel, IPanelSearchSettings } from '../../../../api/generated/models';
import component from '../../components/tables/PanelsTable';
import { getPanels, getPanelsProcessing, getPanelSearchSettings, getPanelFilterValues } from '../../../../store/stream/tracking/panel/selectors';
import { loadPanels } from '../../../../store/stream/tracking/panel/actions';

interface IOwnProps {

}

interface IStateProps {
    panelsLoading: boolean,
    panels: IDataPage<IPanel>,
    searchSettings: IPanelSearchSettings,
    filterValues: IStringMap<any>,
}

interface IDispatchProps {
    loadData: () => void,
    onSearchSettingsChange: (searchSettings: IPanelSearchSettings) => void,
    onFilterChange: (filterValues: IStringMap<any>) => void,
}

const mapStateToProps: MapStateToProps<
    IStateProps,
    IOwnProps,
    IAppState
> = (state: IAppState, ownProps: IOwnProps): IStateProps => ({
    panels: getPanels(state.stream.panel),
    panelsLoading: getPanelsProcessing(state.stream.panel),
    searchSettings: getPanelSearchSettings(state.stream.panel),
    filterValues: getPanelFilterValues(state.stream.panel), 
    ...ownProps
});

const mapDispatchToProps: MapDispatchToProps<
    IDispatchProps,
    IOwnProps
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
> = (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<{}, {}, AnyAction>, ownProps: IOwnProps) => ({
    loadData: async () => {
        dispatch(loadPanels());
    },
    onSearchSettingsChange: (searchSettings: IPanelSearchSettings) => {
        console.log("onPanelSearchSettingsChange [searchSettings]: ", searchSettings);
        dispatch(loadPanels(searchSettings));
    },
    onFilterChange: (filterValues: IStringMap<any>) => {
        console.log("onPanelFilterChange [searchSettings]: ", filterValues);
        dispatch(loadPanels(undefined, filterValues));
    },
});

export default connect<
    IStateProps,
    IDispatchProps,
    IOwnProps,
    IAppState
>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(component);
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood in your code, **PanelsTable** is a connected component that uses the settings part of your state. And you want that to be accessible by **TrackingPage** as well.

You have defined the TypeScript interface for the props of **TrackingPage** like this:

`type IComponentProps = IProps & RouteComponentProps & PanelTableProps & OverlayTableProps;`

But that defines your properties only **compile-time** and doesn't do anything really at runtime.

In your `mapStateToProps` function for **TrackingPage** you haven't defined any settings property in the object returned, so you won't have access to it in that component.

You still need to do that for TrackingPage's `mapStateToProps` too, if it's a union of Panel and Overlay settings, you should define a union there:

```
interface IStateProps {
    panelsLoading: boolean,
    panels: IDataPage<IPanel>,
    overlaysLoading: boolean,
    overlays: IDataPage<IOverlay>,
    searchSettings: IPanelSearchSettings & IOverlaySearchSettings & ...
}

const mapStateToProps: MapStateToProps<
    IStateProps,
    IOwnProps,
    IAppState
> = (state: IAppState, ownProps: IOwnProps): IStateProps => ({
    panels: getPanels(state.stream.panel),
    panelsLoading: getPanelsProcessing(state.stream.panel),
    overlays: getOverlays(state.stream.overlay),
    overlaysLoading: getOverlaysProcessing(state.stream.overlay),
    searchSettings: ... logic for merging settings from panel and overlay goes here...
    ...ownProps
});
```

Comment: Oh, I see, I thought about something is missing inside that mapping, but I wasn't sure how to write it universally. I will try it asap and let you know if it worked.

Comment: I am still not sure how to do the actual assignment of searchSettings property in mapStateToProps. I defined it in IStateProps with the intersection, but I don't know how to make the intersection work

Comment: It's not enough to update the interfaces only, you should update ```mapStateToProps``` of **TrackingPage**. I've updated my comment with a sample to start from. You'll need to decide which parts you need from panel and from overlay and merge them in an object to assign to ```searchSettings```.

Comment: Yeah I understood that. I wasn't able to make it work this way. I ended up changing approach and creating custom TableHeadExtended for every type - i.e. PanelsTableHeadExtended. Not pretty, nor effective, but time is pressuring me. Thanks for the help anyway.